# How to get a colorbar in networkx.draw_networkx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, machine-learning, networkx

I am performing clustering on relational graphs, and am currently using `networkx` to visualize the result:

```
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(X)
layout = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=layout, with_labels=True, node_color=predict, cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

[image]

Is it possible to get a colorbar? Simply using `plt.colorbar()` gives the error:

> `RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf).`

And there aren't any options in the [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html).
I am also open to use another package for visualization as long as it is compatible with Python 3.

Comment: It's not apparent how you create this graph from the question. What the error tells you is that you need to supply an argument to the colorbar function. You may use a [`matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable`](https://matplotlib.org/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable) which uses the same vmin, vmax and colormap as the networks graph and supply it as argument to the colorbar function.

Comment: Updated the question. I am not sure how to use `matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable` simply supplying it to `plt.colorbar()` didn't work. Any pointers?

Comment: Well, according to the usual approach for Stackoverflow questions and answers, you may provide a [mcve] of the issue that I can run, modify and test, such that I can subsequently provide you with an answer, showing the exact code to use here.

Comment: @TokeFaurby, can you provide values for `predict`, so we could reproduce it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a demo based on Karate Club graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.karate_club_graph()

df = (pd.DataFrame(list(G.degree), columns=['node','degree'])
        .set_index('node'))
df['club'] = pd.Series({node:data['club']
                        for node,data in G.nodes(data=True)})
df['color'] = df.groupby('club')['degree'].transform(lambda c: c/c.max())
df.loc[df['club']=='Officer', 'color'] *= -1

layout = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G)
vmin = df['color'].min()
vmax = df['color'].max()
cmap = plt.cm.coolwarm

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=layout, with_labels=True, node_color=df['color'],
                 cmap=cmap, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
sm.set_array([])
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a colorbar?